# Appmaker: send email on submit button when a specific field changes

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an edit tickets page where I want to send an email when a user change the status of the ticket and submit this edit.

I made on click on the submit button to send the email but I don't know how to restrict it if only the status has changed as the way I implemented send the email even if i open the edit ticket page and didn't change anything.

I want to know how to make it when submitting the button of edit ticket on value change of status.

```
var recordKey=widget.datasource.item._key;

var newValue = widget.datasource.item.Status;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().sendStatusChange(recordKey,newValue);
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at the model onBeforeSave event where you have access to the oldRecord and record variable. You can do if(record.Status !== oldRecord.Status) {send email;}. Otherwise you may need to incorporate manual save in your datasource and handle this inside the saveChanges function success handler.

Comment: I made it on before save event and changed to manual save to be able to call the send email function only when the user click on the submit button. But my question that even if I don't click the submit button and closed the window, the changes aren't saved but it is shown in the view table unless I refresh the page.
I want if I close the edit ticket page without clicking the submit button, not to show in the view table the unsaved changes @MarkusMalessa

Comment: You can implement app.datasources.YourDatasource.clearChanges() in your page onDetach event to get this accomplished.

Comment: It worked. Thanks alot @MarkusMalessa. Can you send me your contact details?